# Retornar JSON a blade y mostrarlo con JS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Estoy tratando de retornar un JSON a una vista y mostrarlo con javascript pero me dice :

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable: days
```

En el Controlador instancio el objeto y lo mando a la vista correspondiente

```
public function json()
    {
    $days = Noworkingday::get();
    view('Admin.HomeWidgets.noWorkDays')->with(response()->json($days));
    }
```

En la Vista lo que quiero es que se muestre un calendario donde se pinte de color los dias que le pasa el objeto y su respectivo titulo pero obtengo el error mencionado.

```
@foreach ($days as $item)
    @section('script')
    <script src="{{ asset('template/js/plugins/extensions/jquery_ui/widgets.min.js') }}" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <style media="screen">
    .picker_home .event a {
        background-color: #009688 !important;
        color: #ffffff !important;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $item = {
        //'2021-03-05': 'Feriado nacional',
        'startdate': 'title'
    };

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        beforeShowDay: function( date ) {
            for(x in $item){
                var mes = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                var dia = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
                var fecha = date.getFullYear()+'-'+mes+'-'+dia;

                if (x == fecha) {
                    return [true, "event", $item[x]];
                }
            }
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    });
    </script>
@endforeach
```

Comment: No deberias hacer ese foreach, porque estas importando a cada rato al script por cad iteracion, separa la logica, php-php js-js

Comment: El problema es que en si no le estas dando nombre a tu variable `$days` porque haces un `response`. Por lo que veo, ni es necesario hacerlo, solo devuelve la variable y ya `->with($days)`

Comment: ¿ y luego como lo muestro con JS, puedes ayduarme con eso por favor ?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de dos formas, según mi entendimiento. 1.- A través de ajax y consumes ese json que devuelves o con la directiva de blade `@json($var)` esto puedes almacenarlo en una variable js: `let jsonVar = @json($var);` y puedes usarla en tu javascript

Comment: @Luciano estoy creando una respuesta, aunque no entiendo porque obtienes `$item` y luego quieres sobreescribirlo con `$item = {}`

Comment: no entiendo mucho de JS sinceramente pero tengo que hacerlo de esa forma en el trabajo, gracias por la ayuda !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problemas**

1. Para asignar datos a la vista y mostrarla, no deberias utilizar `response`, ya que esta devuelve una "instancia de estado HTTP" como dice la [documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#response-objects)
2. No deberias hacer ese `foreach` porque estas llamando al script por cada iteracion cosa que esta mal, porque por ejemplo, si se da 10 iteraciones, estarias importando 10 veces "el mismo script"

**Solucion**

- Del primer problema, simplemente devuelve la variable con un `return` asi:

```
public function json()
{
    $days = Noworkingday::get();
    return view('Admin.HomeWidgets.noWorkDays', compact('days'));
}
```

- Del segundo problema, como te dije, tienes que separar la logica, para puedes obtener la variable `$days` por JS y hacer el for normalmente asi:

```
# HTML
<style media="screen">
    .picker_home .event a {
        background-color: #009688 !important;
        color: #ffffff !important;
    }
</style>

# SCRIPTS
<script src="{{ asset('template/js/plugins/extensions/jquery_ui/widgets.min.js') }}" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        //Obtenemos la variable recibida del controlador
        var days = @json($days); // A partir de Laravel 5.5
        // var days = <?php echo json_encode($days); ?>; // Versiones anteriores a la 5.5
        for (const item of days) {
            /* Parte que no entiendo
            $item = {
                //'2021-03-05': 'Feriado nacional',
                'startdate': 'title'
            };*/

            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                beforeShowDay: function( date ) {
                    for(x in item){
                        var mes = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                        var dia = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
                        var fecha = date.getFullYear()+'-'+mes+'-'+dia;

                        if (x == fecha) {
                            return [true, "event", item[x]];
                        }
                    }
                    return [true, '', ''];
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Referencias**

- [compact](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.compact.php)
- [json](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#rendering-json)

Comment: @Luciano que version de laravel tienes? Ya que puse si usar `@json` o `json_encode()`